# Constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

It goes like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // omitted for the sake of brevity...

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public int No { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Manager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoicePayment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class InvoicePayment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoicePaymentParticipant> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class InvoicePaymentParticipant
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid InvoicePaymentId { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoicePayment InvoicePayment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Manager { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Part { get; set; }
}
```

and then I try to `Update-Database` it yells:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'relationship_name' on table 'InvoicePaymentParticipants' may cause >cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other >FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I misunderstand the concept of multiple cascade paths.

I don't understand what the problem is since if we would like to delete a manager we would also expect their payment participation records deleted as well as any invoices they created.

How would you resolve this in the schema given?

Comment: that's not what "multiple cascade paths" mean. SQL server does not allow multiple cascade paths to reach the same table (though it is possible theoretically), which in your example happens i.e. in the paths Invoice->Manager, Invoice->Payments -> Participants->Manager

Comment: How can I redesign these tables to avoid the error?

Comment: make one of the relationships optional and/or disable cascade delete for the constraint (in the model builder)

Comment: IMO,You cannot define Trusted FK on denormalize column.Like ManagerId is define in multiple place.It has to be remove from one place or atleast remove IsRequire attribute.check that after doing this if it is throwing error or not.This point is also good, like if you are deleting Category then all its Order detail should be delete or not.

Comment: You may find this useful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193292/is-it-a-good-practice-to-build-in-as-many-foreign-keys-as-possible/193296#193296

Answer (score 5):

Cascading delete is enabled by default when you create a foreign key relationship on a required (or non-nullable) property, see [EF required relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#required-relationships)

The problem here is that you have 2 cascading delete paths from `InvoicePaymentParticipant` to your `ApplicationUser` table:

```
Path1: InvoicePaymentParticipant -> InvoicePayment -> Invoice -> ApplicationUser

Path2: InvoicePaymentParticipant -> ApplicationUser
```

This means, when you delete a user, the following records should be deleted:

**Deletions under path 1:**

1. when *user* is deleted, delete his *invoices*
2. when *invoice* is deleted, delete corresponding *invoice payments*
3. when *invoice payment* is deleted, delete corresponding *invoice payment participants*

**Deletions under path 2:**

1. when *user* is deleted, delete his *invoice payment participants*

This is not allowed in Sql Server. See [this page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/) for more info.

To solve the problem, you can reconsider your table structure and remove one of the foreign key paths from `InvoicePaymentParticipant` to `ApplicationUser`...

The other approach would be to change the cascading delete behavior of the foreign key, you can remove the `[Required]` attribute on one of the `ManagerId` properties and since `string` is a `nullable` type, EF would set the [key to null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#optional-relationships) on delete.

You can also change EF default behavior and [turn off cascading delete](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: This is good advice, in my apps I generally disable the cascading delete convention and manually specify which relationships I want to allow the cascading scenario. Consider this, if User X pays an invoice, and User X is deleted, do you really want the invoice to also be deleted? Its hard to balance your books and maintain financial history if you allow deleting of the financial records.